# heapq.nsmallest on nested dictionary innermost value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of form

```
myNestedDict=collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

with example data:

```
{'509582':{'509533': 65.499}, 
 '509583':{'509534': -35.499},{'509568': -325.499},
 '509584':{'509576': 0},{'509576': -1337} }
```

And I am trying to get it to return both keys associated with the n smallest per value.

So for this example if I am looking for 2 smallest: heapq.nsmallest(2, myNestedDict, key=???)

I would like to return the dictionary:

```
{'509584':{'509576': -1337},
'509583':{'509568': -325.499} }
```

or,I actually don't really need the value anymore so it could return a non-nested dictionary if easier:

```
{'509584':'509576',
'509583':'509568'}
```

As you can see, I can't figure out a proper key design for the heapq.nsmallest to sort on the innermost value.  Any help hugely appreciated. Thanks

NOTE - this dictionary is many millions of records, so efficiency is important.

edit - this right here is what I have that actually runs, but its sorting on the first key only, I need to sort on the innermost value.  note, they say itemgetter is way faster that lambda for this multi-million sized dictionary

heapq.nsmallest( 2, myNestedDict.items(), key=itemgetter(0) )

Comment: Something like `key=lambda k: min(myNestedDict[k].values())`?

Comment: Bakuriu, i get: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Your example data now isn't even syntactically a valid dictionary.

Comment: Scott, I'm trying to correct it right now.

Comment: How are you calling the function? I'd expect the `key` function to be called with the dictionary keys as argument, but it seems like it ends up getting the values, which suggest you are using something like `nsmallest(2, myNestedDict.values(),...)` instead of `nsmallest(2, myNestedDict, ...)`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Actually it *is* syntactically valid to have equal keys: `$ python -c 'print({"a": 1, "a": 2})'` outputs `{'a': 2}`, i.e. the last occurrence overrides previous values

Comment: heapq.nsmallest( 2,myNestedDict, key=lambda k: min(myNestedDict[k].values()) )

now giving me: unorderable types: dict() < dict()

Comment: @Bakuriu: I didn't say that was syntactically invalid.

Comment: heapq.nsmallest( 2, myNestedDict, key=lambda f,t: myNestedDict[f][t].values )

<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by converting my nested dictionary into a list of tuples using list comprehension and then using heapq.nsmallest(2, myTupleList, key=itemgetter(2) ).

Performance is manageable because it only takes 0.5 sec to convert the dictionary to a list for a 1 million row example.